# Procedimiento almacenado de seguridad

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Estoy haciendo un procedimiento almacenado que me saque un mensaje de error si un campo en especifico esta vacio al hacer el insert, pero no logro que me funcione

```
IF @object_type IN ('13')
    AND @transaction_type IN (
        'A'
        ,'U'
        )
BEGIN
    IF (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM OINV T0
            INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T1.DocEntry = T0.DocEntry
            INNER JOIN NNM1 T2 ON T2.Series = T0.Series
            WHERE IsNull(T0.U_Placa_Vehiculo,'') = ''
                aND T0.DocEntry = @list_of_cols_val_tab_del
                AND T2.SeriesName = 'FAE-PB' 
            ) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @error = 13024
        SET @error_message = 'SP: Este documento no se puede crear sin placa'
    END
END
```

el campo con el que necesito hacer la validacion es T0.U_Placa_Vehiculo

Comment: ¿Qué valor tiene @list_of_cols_val_tab_del? ¿@object_type?  ¿@transaction_type? El valor de T0.U_Placa_Vehiculo es '' o podría ser NULL?

Comment: esos son campos con los cuales valido los documentos y el numero de transaccion en el insert, el valor de T0.U_Placa_Vehiculo es un valor Nvarchar por lo que es la placa de un auto, pero necesito que si este va vacio me saque el mensaje de error para que no deje realizar el insert

Comment: Añade más información para que podamos intentar ayudarte. Así, sin saber más, se me ocurre que estás validando que T0.U_Placa_Vehiculo es la cadena vacía, ¿estás seguro de que no tendrías que comprobar si es NULL?

Comment: si, ya lo solucione, valide si era null y le puse otro filtro por serie, actualizo el codigo de la pregunta por el codigo funcional

Comment: @KevinRestrepo por favor, pon la solución *como respuesta* a la pregunta para que otros sepan cómo lo resolviste

Comment: En vez de usar COUNT(), prueba utilizando EXISTS(). Es mucho más eficiente para validar existencia de datos. Por cierto, esta validación debería estar antes del INSERT, no después.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agregue una validacion antes del campo T0.U_Placa_Vehiculo para validar que se cumpliera si estaba vacia o Null, adicional otro filtro en el WHERE para que se ejecutara solo cuando estuviera la serie 'FAE-PB'

```
 IF @object_type IN ('13')
            AND @transaction_type IN (
                'A'
                ,'U'
                )
        BEGIN
            IF (
                    SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM OINV T0
                    INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T1.DocEntry = T0.DocEntry
                    INNER JOIN NNM1 T2 ON T2.Series = T0.Series
                    WHERE IsNull(T0.U_Placa_Vehiculo,'') = ''
                        aND T0.DocEntry = @list_of_cols_val_tab_del
                        AND T2.SeriesName = 'FAE-PB' 
                    ) > 0
            BEGIN
                SET @error = 13024
                SET @error_message = 'SP: Este documento no se puede crear sin placa'
            END
        END
```